# MSMQ: do 2 servers need to be in same domain to be able to access private queues?

Tags: wcf, msmq, rhino, rhino-esb

As the title says - i have 3 servers:

server-1 [wcf services]
server-2 [wcf services]
server-3 [esb using rhino.esb]

So - 
server 1 publishes message to server-3 esb
server 2 subscribes to messages from server 1 via server-3 esb

do they all need to be in the same domain or anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security there is no difference between public and private queues - "public" just means published in Active Directory.

Also, you need to differentiate between "different domain" and "different forest". I assume you mean the latter. Two domains in the same forest share the same security database so would not be a problem.

Do not regard Access Control Lists on queues as being a robust form of security. A message can be sent with the SID of any account to get round the queue permissions. Authentication with internel (MSMQ) or external certificates is a much better alternative if security is an issue.

- [How to send authenticated MSMQ messages without using a domain account](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2009/01/23/how-to-send-authenticated-msmq-messages-without-using-a-domain-account.aspx)
- [Authenticating MSMQ messages between forests](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2008/10/13/authenticating-msmq-messages-between-forests.aspx)
- [Cross-forest MSMQ? You need to be trusting](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2008/06/27/cross-forest-msmq-you-need-to-be-trusting.aspx)
- ["How do I send MSMQ messages between domains?"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2008/02/14/how-do-i-send-msmq-messages-between-domains.aspx)
- [Understanding how MSMQ security blocks RPC traffic](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2010/03/24/understanding-how-msmq-security-blocks-rpc-traffic.aspx)

Cheers
John Breakwell

Answer (score 0):

No. But its less secure or more complicated. Depending if you are using no security ( everyone has access) or certificates.
Look at [Securing Messages Using Transport Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789030.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Private queues are just accessed via a TCP port, so there is no need for the hosting server to even be on a domain for the MSMQ queue to be accessible. However, I would recommend that you apply transport-level security at the network layer (i.e. firewalls) to prevent any unauthorised traffic from putting messages on / retrieving from the queues.